# Start a Thread with same as parent security context in C#.net

Tags: c#, .net, com

I have a method that spawns a new thread as follows:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() => ClassObject.SetXY(var1, var2));
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);               
thread.Start();
thread.Join();
```

I currently get access denied `(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))` Exception from the COM interop I am trying.
I do not get that exception when I run the function in same parent thread. However, I need it to run in separate thread to set the apartment state to STA. I am currently running my code as windows service and even when I use [STAThread] on the main method I do not get that to work.

Briefly What I need:

- 1- either start a thread (STA) like above that has same security
  context as parent thread.
- 2- do not start a new thread (this will solve access denied issue but
  will throw an exception due to the apartment state of thread not
  being STA) but make the thread of the windows service run in STA
  apartment state.

Thanks

Comment: Try using ThreadPool it does copy caller security context.

Comment: @user629926: haven't used that before , can you  show some code how I can do above using threadpool?

Comment: I found it it uses internaly an ExecutionxContext try looking into that.  I meant  just call ThreadPoll.QueieUserWorkItem instead creating new thread.

Comment: @user629926 - ThreadPool will not help here as one can't control STA/MTA mode on threads in thread-pool to my knowledge. Looking at how context is set in thread-pool code/copying it sounds like an option.

Answer (score 0):

You could copy the parent thread's execution context and then run your code in that context on the spawned thread:

```
var executionContext = ExecutionContext.Capture();
Thread thread = new Thread(state => {
    ExecutionContext parentContext = (ExecutionContext)state;
    ExecutionContext.Run(parentContext, _ => {
        ClassObject.SetXY(var1, var2);
    }, null);
});

thread.Start(executionContext);
```

Comment: I do still `E_ACCESSDENIED` with this solution.